# DateTime and DataMapper

Tags: ruby, datetime, datamapper

## Problem

I'm essentially trying to save +4 hours from now in DM. I think the DateTime is correct, but the DataMapper doesn't work properly. Any ideas?

## Controller

```
p DateTime.now
t = DateTime.now + params[:hours] / 24
p t
reward = @player.work params[:hours]
action = Action.new(:player => @player, :type => 0, :completed_at => t, :reward => reward)
```

## model

```
class Action
include DataMapper::Resource

property :id, Serial
property :type, Integer
property :completed_at, DateTime
property :reward, Integer

TYPES = {
  0 => "Work",
  1 => "Arena",
  2 => "Quest"
}

validates_with_method :type, :method => :valid_type?

def valid_type?
  if TYPES.key? self.type.to_i
    true
  else
    [false, "Invalid action type."]
  end
end

def get_type
  case TYPES[self.type]
  when "Work"
    "you're working"
  when "Arena"
    "in the arena"
  when "Quest"
    "in a quest"
  end
end

 belongs_to :player
end
```

Comment: could you formulate the problem a bit clearer and without your domain specific stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:
DateTime.now + (params[:hours] / 24.0)